# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I Want to permanently delete all deleted SP Site site from recycle bin and throw this error,"  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null."

Get-SPODeletedSite | foreach {  $*.url}| Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity $*.url
Remove-SPODeletedSite : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
At line:1 char:74

- ... etedSite | foreach {  $*.url}| Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity $*.url
- ```
                                                                 ~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-SPODeletedSite], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.RemoveSPODeletedSite

```
I run  Get-SPODeletedsite |foreach {$_.url} and retrieve all deleted site. then use pipeline and Remove-SPODeletedsite -Identity $_.url but can't delete .

Any help is Appreciated!
```

Comment: ```Get-SPODeletedSite | %{Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity $.url}``` should do the trick

Comment: `Get-SPODeletedSite | Remove-SPODeletedSite`